# Variable passed into backbone view coming up undefined

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am in the process of learning backbone / underscore, and I am finding that the more I break away from the really basic stuff in the tutorials, the more come to realize that the tutorials aren't teaching me much of anything.

My current problem is with passing a variable to a view. I have three different templates available, but they all render the same, so I was hoping to just pass which template to use into the view when it was being rendered from the collection. What I thought would work would be just adding a property to the call to the view, and then accessing it with this.options.Property, but this is throwing an error that the property is undefined.

I have tried a number of variant options, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks is advance.

```
var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#projectList',
    initialize: function() {
      this.collection = masterProjectList;
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html("");
      this.collection.each(function(project) {
            this.renderItem(project);
      }, this);
    },
    renderItem: function(project) {
      var projectView = new ProjectView({model: project, projectType: '#theatricalProjectTemplate' });
    // Passing in the project type, which determines which template gets used
      this.$el.append(projectView.render().el);
    }
  });

  var ProjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "project-wrap",
    template: _.template($(this.options.projectType).html()),
        // use this.options to access the value

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    }
  });
```

Comment: What do you think `this` is when you `_.template($(this.options.projectType).html())`?

Comment: I assumed it referred to the individual view being created- IE the variables and states as they exist for that one view. Did I make an ass out of U and MED?

Comment: Eh, don't feel bad - I looked at it and didn't realize what was going on.

Comment: how your template looks like?

Comment: You should see some of the mistakes I've made :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're defining your `ProjectView`:

```
var ProjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
  //...
  template: _.template($(this.options.projectType).html()),
  //...
});
```

you're executing some code (i.e. calling `extend`) and in this context, `this` will be the global object (AKA `window` in a browser) and that probably won't have an `options` property. If you want to use the `projectType` option that you pass to the `ProjectView` constructor, move the `template` assignment into `initialize`:

```
var ProjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "div",
  className: "project-wrap",
  initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template($(this.options.projectType).html());
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

This assumes that `projectType` will be a valid jQuery selector, you might want to use `'#' + this.options.projectType` instead but I'm not sure what exactly will be in `projectType`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that by moving the compilation of the template into `initialize` you end up compiling the template for each *projectView*. Depending on how many projects there are it might be a better idea to compile the three templates once and pass in the actaul compiled template to the view instead.

Comment: @Jack: Or set up a separate "template manager" object to compile and cache the templates on first use or compile them all during deployment and just index into a global `JST` array of template functions.

Comment: This did it. Thanks! I only though I had figure out _this_, I still need to study it.

Comment: @muistooshort True, I was focusing more on the compiling it once instead of for every view instance. I said to pass it in since from what I understood the OP wanted to be able to decide when instantiating the view which template to use.

Answer (score -1):

`mu is too short` is correct and if you define `template` method as follows, you can share the `template` method with all instances of `ProjectView`:

```js
var ProjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "div",
  className: "project-wrap",
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
  template: function() {
    return _.template($(this.options.projectType).html());
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to say `this.template()(this.model.toJSON())`?